# UIScrollView breaks when using autolayout for size on iOS 8 / Xcode 6 GM Seed

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios8, xcode6

How do I get a Scroll View to work using autolayout to calculate its content size?

It seems Xcode 6 will create a "UIView Encapsulated Layout Height" constraint whenever a Scroll View (with Autolayout) exists, and this constraint will forcibly set the height to the frame height (thus rendering the scroll functionality of a scroll view useless).

[image: Layout broken - iPhone 5s Simulator in Xcode 6 GM Seed]

Error:

```
2014-09-09 21:06:01.059 ScrollViewLayoutBreaking[24488:88731] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9a19ebd150 V:[UIView:0x7f9a19ea7f90(530)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9a19ec1370 V:[UIView:0x7f9a19ebd5e0(110)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9a19ea9ee0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9a19ec18d0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9a19ea7f90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9a19ec1fa0 V:[UIView:0x7f9a19ea7f90]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9a19ebd5e0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9a19e8d270 V:[UIView:0x7f9a19ebd5e0]-(5)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9a19ec2260]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9a19ea0ac0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9a19ec18d0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9a19ea7380 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9a19ec18d0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7f9a19ea76a0 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9a19e21d00 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9a19ec2260(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9a19e8a930 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9a19ec2260.bottom == UIScrollView:0x7f9a19ea76a0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9a1c003f50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIScrollView:0x7f9a19ea76a0(504)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9a19ebd150 V:[UIView:0x7f9a19ea7f90(530)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Edit: All views inside this Scroll View are autolayouted and already pinned to both the Scroll View top and bottom, as well as both sides. I am aware that failing to bind it in all four sides will fail to create a content size. The autolayout and scrolling are correct in iOS 7 / XCode 5, but the exact same code and storyboard break in iOS 8 / XCode 6.

Comment: Reworded question to make it shorter and clearer. Currently using Xcode 6 GM Seed.

Comment: The best I was able to come up with was a table view with a single self sizing cell which will act as the scroll view, separator style none. But this is horrible enough for me to use it as an absolutely last resort.

Comment: Why was this closed? It's valid question.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on constraint from what to what, and frame of what?  If this is just a general question, there are numerous examples and posts, but you have to set the edges of the content view to those of the parent scroll view, and set equal width and height constraints from the content view to the scroll view.  Doing so will result in a scrolling content view when the content view exceeds the size of the parent scroll view.  Auto layout is a "bear" to learn, but works when you get it.  You can do all this in IB, FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I'd answer the question since it's receiving replies up to this day.

The code is autolayouted correctly. As stated in the question, the same code produced a perfect, no warning/errors Scroll View using Xcode 5 and iOS 7, and would break a layout constraint I did not manually create in Xcode 6 GM Seed and iOS 8.

It so seems it was an Xcode 6 GM Seed bug, the same code actually worked seamlessly in future updates of Xcode 6 after the first release, without any constraint breaking.

Answer (score 0):

By your Screenshot, I'm guessing that you are using custom views in a scrollview so...

Your Content Views Are : STH,Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux,Blah,Woot,Lorem,Ipsum, Dolor

In code you can set the content size automatically with autolayout by setting all your content views related by each other, with the exception of the top and bottom view... these ones must be related to the edges of the scrollview, Here is an Example:

```
-(void)example{

UIView *parentView; //Can be the Scroll View or the Scroll View superview, it's better for the ScrollView to be the Owner of the restrictions
UIView *previousView;
UIScrollView *scrollView;

NSArray * arrayOfContentViews = @[STH,Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux,Blah,Woot,Lorem,Ipsum,Dolor];

for (UIView * currentView in arrayOfContentViews) {

    //Important for Autolayout Restrictions
    currentView.translateAutoresizingMask = NO;
    [scrollview addSubview:currentView];

    if (previousView == nil) {
        //For the Top, Left and Right Attribute Edges of the ScrollView
        previousView = scrollView;

        [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:previousView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];

        //10% of the scrollview Frame Size (not Content Size)
        [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                                  toItem:previousView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              multiplier:0.1
                                                                constant:0.0]];            

    }else{

        [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:previousView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];

        [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:previousView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];
    }

    [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:previousView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0.0]];

    [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:previousView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0.0]];


    previousView = currentView;

    }

//Last View Dolor to the Bottom Edge of the scrollView
[parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:previousView
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:scrollView
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:0.0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IB, then select the UIViewController and select remove all constraints from the AutoLayout menu at the bottom. Then select add missing constraints. This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For UIScrollView to work vertically it needs the chain of subviews from top to bottom.

Now if you set the top/bottom margin of its subviews you left no idea to scroll view how it should render it self vertically as it calculates its own height based on its content

So what you should do is allow scrollview to determine its own height independent of its children.

So add your scrollview in another view as subview with constraint related to that view and then you are free to add children relative to scrollview.